# Leetcode 205: Isomorphic Strings

Tags: python, dictionary

My code is failing this testcase. Can someone please help me understand what is incorrect with my code?

Input:
"badc"
"baba"
Output:
true
Expected:
false

```
class Solution(object):
    def isIsomorphic(self, s, t):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type t: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        dict = {}
        
        if len(s)==0 or len(t)==0:
            return False
        
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in dict:
                if dict[s[i]] != t[i]:
                    return False
            else:
                dict[s[i]] = t[i]
        return True
```

Comment: In your else clause you need to check whether `t[i]` already existed as a value in the mapping dict (because two different chars are not allowed to map to same char)

Answer (score 0):

you have checked that for 1 string only, ie is `s` isomorphic to `t` or not?
you need to check that also for `t`, ie is `t` isomorphic to `s` or not?

```
class Solution(object):
    def isIsomorphic(self, s, t):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type t: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        dict = {}
        dict2 = {}
        
        if len(s)==0 or len(t)==0:
            return False
        if len(s)!= len(t):
            return False
        for a,b in zip(s,t):
            if a not in dict:
                dict[a]=b
            else:
                if dict[a]!=b:
                    return False
            if b not in dict2:
                dict2[b] = a
            else:
                if dict2[b]!=a:
                    return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the problem description:

> No two characters may map to the same character

For input `s = badc` and `t = baba`, letter `b` and `d` in `s` both map to letter `b` in `t`, which violated the rule and should return false.

As mentioned by [bui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8990644/bui), we can add a condition in the else clause, to make sure values in the dict are unique:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isIsomorphic(self, s, t):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type t: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        dict = {}
        
        if len(s)==0 or len(t)==0:
            return False
        
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in dict:
                if dict[s[i]] != t[i]:
                    return False
            else:
                if t[i] in dict.values():  
                    return False
                dict[s[i]] = t[i]
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more pythonic solution:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isIsomorphic(self, s, t):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type t: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return [s.index(ch) for ch in s] == [t.index(ch) for ch in t]
```

It's equivalent to:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isIsomorphic(self, s, t):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type t: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return [*map(s.index, s)] == [*map(t.index, t)]
```